# Crystal Reports : SQL Server does not exist or access denied

Tags: sql, asp.net, database, sql-server-2012, crystal-reports

complete Crystal Reports noob here.

I am having trouble runing a Crystal report since I changed database servers. essentially I set up the exact opy of our database including users and passwords with only the IP changing. When I change the IP in the report connection I get the following:

```
Logon failed. Details: ADO Error Code: 0x Source: Microsoft OLE DB 
Provider for SQL Server Description: [DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen
(Connect()).]SQL Server does not exist or access denied. SQL State: 
08001 Native Error: Error in File C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\temp_b87d4210-
ce32-4059-8257-c0441088d08a {815D8B1D-1C68-4B65-9CEE-936A1ACFA47B}.rpt: 
Unable to connect: incorrect log on parameters.
```

I have already opened and checked the firewall on the SQL server to make sure it is open and have used a rule we use for other websites to connect. I have also checked the firewall log for any rejections but this is completely empty.

I have checked the SQL server is running for both named pipes and TCP/IP (and default port).

Has anyopne any ideas why this connection is not working?

Thanks for you time. All suggestions greatly appreciated.

JB

Comment: Can you open the Crystal Report in the Crystal Report designer to see if it runs from there? There may be a connection hard coded in the report.

Comment: As I mentioned I am a complete novice to Crystal and I have no idea how to do this. I will give it a try. Installing Crystal for Visual Studio as we speak. Thanks.  :)